# Importing Database from Local to Emulator & vice versa for SQLite (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, import

I am developing an android project (Eclipse java - Emulator 5554 - SQLite).

But I don't know how to import or export databases. Please look at the code below first

code segment 1: (this code segment is in onClick method of a button in android device)

```
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {               SQLiteDatabase db =  openOrCreateDatabase("EOS_DB_TRY_OUT", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

            DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(getBaseContext(), DB_NAME, null,1);
            dbConnector.onCreate(db);

// private static String DB_PATH = "assets/database/eosdatabase.zip";
    //private static String DB_NAME = "eosdatabase.db";  these are global variables in //class...

    }
```

Code segment 2: This is another class in which I am trying to create(or use existing one if it exists) and connect

```
public class DatabaseConnector extends SQLiteOpenHelper {





public DatabaseConnector(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    System.out.println("On create works");

            try {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS actuator;");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actuator ("+
                        "ACTUATOR_ID INT NOT NULL,"+
                        "ACTUATOR_HW_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "DEVICE_NAME TEXT(45) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "DEVICE_TYPE TEXT(45) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "DEVICE_SUB_TYPE TEXT(45) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "LOCATION_ID INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "STATUES_VALUE REAL DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "MAX_STATUES_VALUE REAL DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "MIN_STATUES_VALUE REAL DEFAULT NULL,"+
                        "PRIMARY KEY (`ACTUATOR_ID`))");

                System.out.println("table created now values will be added");



            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("table is not created");
            }

            try {

                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO actuator (ACTUATOR_ID, ACTUATOR_HW_ID, DEVICE_NAME, DEVICE_TYPE, DEVICE_SUB_TYPE, LOCATION_ID, STATUES_VALUE, MAX_STATUES_VALUE, MIN_STATUES_VALUE) " +
                        "VALUES (4,2, 'Heat Sensor FX615','Heat Sensor', 'Optic Heat Sensor', 4, 6, 7, 8) " );
                System.out.println("values are added");
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("values are not added");
            }

            try 
            {
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT LOCATION_ID FROM actuator WHERE ACTUATOR_ID = 4", null);
                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) 
                {


                        String berkay = c.getString(0);
                        System.out.println(berkay);

                }
                System.out.println("select finished");

            } 
            catch (SQLiteException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("not selected");
            }
```

The thing is:

The code is working, syntax is right but I was working on it yesterday without any external database and code was creating new database when executing and deleting it after execution because I was just testing syntax. Now code is working well but I don't know which database the code is using.

Today I am making a database via sqliteadmin database browser and I want to use it in emulator (not creating new database and deleting it for every execution, I want permanent database). I don't understand this code, Is this code creating new one and deleting it like what I did before ? If so, how can I import the external database and use it?

note : the name of database which I want to use is "eosdatabase" and the location of it desktop/databasefolder/database/eosdatabase.zip/eosdatabase.s3db

note2: after importing external database into emulator database file, how can i connect that database (if you solve my code problem i would be happy not only importing database into emulator, I need code instead of the one above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For copying database from phone to local system.**

Go to DDMS -> File-explorer -> data -> data -> your application package name -> database. Here select the database which you want to export to local system, then go to top right corner of the window there you will find export button , click that button it will ask the destination location then chose location and press ok.

**For copying database from local system  to phone.**

Go to DDMS -> File-explorer -> data -> data -> your application package name -> database.  then go to top right corner of the window there you will find import button , click that button then it will ask source location browse the location select the database then press OK..

Comment: well thanks for this info that was a part of what I am looking for but for the code, How can I modify code to connect database (after copying my database from local system to phone)